# two queries give different results in the same database

Tags: mysql

Please help. I'm using MySQL 5.1.30 Community Edition.

I have four tables: nts, operator, country, cooperationtype

- table `nts` has one column(`operatorId`) which is a foreign key to column `id` in table `operator` and one column(`voice`) which is a foreign key to column `id` in table cooperationtype
- table operator has one column(`country_id`) which is a foreign key to column (`id`) in table country

I want to get the counts of operators and countries where all of the value of voice not equals to 'N/A' and grouped them by cooperationtype.id with this query:

`SELECT cooperationtype.id AS cooptype, 
COUNT(DISTINCT country_id) AS country, COUNT(DISTINCT operatorId) AS operator 
FROM nts INNER JOIN operator ON operator.id = nts.operatorId INNER JOIN country ON operator.country_id = country.id 
INNER JOIN cooperationtype ON cooperationtype.id = nts.voice 
WHERE cooperationtype.code <> 'N/A' GROUP BY cooperationtype.id`

I got this result:

```
cooptype   country    operator
1         128          348
2         11           11
3         15           17
```

The sum of this query is 154 countries and 376 operators.

But then when I want to get all of the counts of operators and countries where all of the value of voice not equals to 'N/A', regardless the of cooperationtype.id with this query:

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT country_id) AS country, COUNT(DISTINCT operatorId) AS operator 
FROM nts INNER JOIN operator ON operator.id = nts.operatorId INNER JOIN country ON operator.country_id = country.id 
INNER JOIN cooperationtype ON cooperationtype.id = nts.voice 
WHERE cooperationtype.code <> 'N/A'`

I got this result:

```
country operator
133     372
```

My questions are:

1. Why is the sum of the result from the first query doesn't equal to the result from the second query?
2. Which one is the right result?

Data example:

```
voice     country   operator
1         US        1  
1         US        2  
1         UK        3  
1         UK        4  
2         US        1  
2         US        2
```

For the first query, the data should generate:

```
cooptype  country   operator 
1         2         4 
2         2         2
```

For the second query, the data should generate:

```
country   operator 
2         4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is the sum of the result from the first query doesn't equal to the result from the second query?

Because you use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.

It counts distinct records group-wise.

Your first query counts two records with the same country but different `cooptype` twice (since it groups by `cooptype`), while the second one counts them once.

> Which one is the right result?

Both are right.

For the given data:

```
cooptype  country
1         US
1         US
1         UK
1         UK
2         US
2         US
```

the first query will return:

```
1         2
2         1
```

and the second will return

```
2
```

, since you have:

- `2` distinct countries in `cooptype = 1` (`US` and `UK`)
- `1` distinct country in `cooptype = 2` (`US`)
- `2` distinct countries overall (`US` and `UK`)

Which is "right" in your definition of "right", depends, well, on this definition.

If you just want the second query to match the results of the first one, use

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT cootype, country_id) AS country,
        COUNT(DISTINCT cooptype, operatorId) AS operator
FROM    nts
INNER JOIN
        operator
ON      operator.id = nts.operatorId
INNER JOIN
        country
ON      operator.country_id = country.id
INNER JOIN
        cooperationtype
ON      cooperationtype.id = nts.voice
WHERE   cooperationtype.code <> 'N/A'
```

but, again, this may be as wrong as your first query is.

For these data:

```
cooptype  country  operator
1         US       1
1         US       1
1         UK       2
1         UK       2
2         US       1
2         US       1
```

, what would be a correct resultset?

Comment: The result expected for second query is to get all of the operators and countries count in nts table. So should I just use the result from the first query and sum it?

Comment: @Hamdan: you have `DISTINCT` in your query. Is it on purpose? Also, please don't put the code in comments: instead make it an update to your own post. Please add the appropriate fields into my sample dataset and post the desired output of the query. I would need to write a correct query.

Comment: @Hamdan: if that's what you want, then both of your queries are correct. As you can see, the numbers of distinct countries within the groups do not add up to the total numbers of distinct countries.

Comment: @Quassnoi: I understand the countries count. How about the operator count? The result should at least match between the first and second query, right?

Comment: @Hamdan: I updated my sample, providing duplicates for the operators (since you are having them in your data). What would be the correct output for this recordset?

Comment: @Quassnoi: you can't have the same operatorId in different countries. At least the UK should have different ids.

Comment: @Hamdan: from the output of your query I see that in your data you are having them (probably not in different countries, but in different cooptypes). Please see the updated recordset.

Comment: @Quassnoi: I've updated the data example. I just realized now I can't have the same sum result with these two queries. thanks for your help.

Comment: @Hamdan: you're welcome. If it was useful, please check it as accepted (click on the check mark under the vote count)